# Android Gradle таски

Tags: android, gradle

Нужно выполнить свой gradle task до того, как начнет выполняться блок зависимостей, чтобы инициализировать `myVariable`:

```
dependencies {
    compile (foo + myVariable)
}
```

Как называется task, который выполняет блок dependencies?

**UPD:** попробовал `println` в блоке `dependencies`, `println` сработал до вывода графа тасков:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]